# Add index to child elements within XML file Python

Tags: python, xml, indexing

I´m a novice in python, so please help. I´d like to add an index to `row` and `column` elements in same way like `page` elements have index.

Within page 1 there are 4 rows, so the index would go from 0 to 3. Within page 1, row 0 there is only one column, so index would be only 0.
In page 1, row 2 there  are 3 columns, so index for columns would go from 0 to 2. The same for the other rows in other pages.

I've been beginning testing with Elementree but only the basics to print elements. Maybe someone could help me with this.

I have the following code for basic testings only but I don´t know how to proceed with this.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('smp.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for text in root.iter('text'):
    print(text.attrib)

for text in root.iter('text'):
    print(text.text)
```

The input XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <page index="0"/>
    <page index="1">
        <row>
            <column>
                <text>fibrous drupe</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row>
            <column>
                <text>follicle</text>
            </column>
            <column>
                <text>legume</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row>
            <column>
                <text>loment</text>
            </column>
            <column>
                <text>nut</text>
            </column>
            <column>
                <text>samara</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row>
            <column>
                <text>schizocarp</text>
            </column>
        </row>
    </page>
    <page index="2">
        <row>
            <column>
                <text>cypsela</text>
            </column>
        </row>
    </page>
    <page index="3"/>
</doc>
```

and I would like to convert it to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <page index="0"/>
    <page index="1">
        <row index="0">
            <column index="0">
                <text>fibrous drupe</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row index="1">
            <column index="0">
                <text>follicle</text>
            </column>
            <column index="1">
                <text>legume</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row index="2">
            <column index="0">
                <text>loment</text>
            </column>
            <column index="1">
                <text>nut</text>
            </column>
            <column index="2">
                <text>samara</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row index="3">
            <column index="0">
                <text>schizocarp</text>
            </column>
        </row>
    </page>
    <page index="2">
        <row index="0">
            <column index="0">
                <text>cypsela</text>
            </column>
        </row>
    </page>
    <page index="3"/>
</doc>
```

I hope make sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below

('56403870.xml' is the XML you have posted)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('56403870.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

pages = root.findall('.//page')
for page in pages:
    rows = page.findall('.//row')
    for r, row in enumerate(rows):
        row.attrib['index'] = str(r)
        columns = row.findall('.//column')
        for c, col in enumerate(columns):
            col.attrib['index'] = str(c)

ET.dump(tree)
```

output

```
<doc>
    <page index="0" />
    <page index="1">
        <row index="0">
            <column index="0">
                <text>fibrous drupe</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row index="1">
            <column index="0">
                <text>follicle</text>
            </column>
            <column index="1">
                <text>legume</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row index="2">
            <column index="0">
                <text>loment</text>
            </column>
            <column index="1">
                <text>nut</text>
            </column>
            <column index="2">
                <text>samara</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row index="3">
            <column index="0">
                <text>schizocarp</text>
            </column>
        </row>
    </page>
    <page index="2">
        <row index="0">
            <column index="0">
                <text>cypsela</text>
            </column>
        </row>
    </page>
    <page index="3" />
</doc>
```

Comment: Thank you balderman. It works nice. I see 3 loops are needed!

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to python meself, so you have to finish this yourself:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('smp.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for text in root:
    print(text.tag, text.attrib)
    for text2 in text:
        print(" ", text2.tag, text2.attrib)
        if (text2.tag=='row'):
           text2.set('index','42')

tree.write('output.xml')
```

In 'output.xml' you will get:

```
<doc>
    <page index="0" />
    <page index="1">
        <row index="42">
            <column>
                <text>fibrous drupe</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row index="42">
            <column>
                <text>follicle</text>
            </column>
            <column>
                <text>legume</text>
            </column>
        </row>
        <row index="42">
            <column>
               ….
```

So, you need to change those '42' to the value you need them to be.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and your approach in how to accomplish this Luuk. Best regards

Comment: @Parfait Hi. It doesn't work for me the solution :(

Comment: @Parfait is not an error, simply the output is not as expected

Comment: @Ger: Do you need help with this? or.... (I am a bit confused about what to do when reading above comments )

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for your help Luuk. Since both are new to Python, we can benefit from balderman's solution that works as expected. Thanks anyway